# Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '10.8' to data type in

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I am getting the error "Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '10.8' to data type in.".

I am writing this query in Azure Data warehouse.
What could be wrong i am not doing any conversion to Int.

```
select 
  cast(
    case
        when [total_amount] is null then 0
        when [total_amount] = '' then 0
        else [total_amount]
    end
    as decimal(10,4)
)
  FROM [dbo].[ABC]
```

This Query is an external table query which is also reporting error
6 rows rejected from external table [NYCTaxiData] in plan step 2 of query execution:

```
Location: '/2016/yellow_tripdata_2016-07.csv' Column ordinal: 17, Expected data type: VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value: VendorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this line.
    Location: '/2016/yellow_tripdata_2016-10.csv' Column ordinal: 17, Expected data type: VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value: VendorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this line.
    Location: '/2016/yellow_tripdata_2016-11.csv' Column ordinal: 17, Expected data type: VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value: VendorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this line.
    Location: '/2016/yellow_tripdata_2016-09.csv' Column ordinal: 17, Expected data type: VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value: VendorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this line.
    Location: '/2016/yellow_tripdata_2016-08.csv' Column ordinal: 17, Expected data type: VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value: VendorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this line.
    Location: '/2016/yellow_tripdata_2016-12.csv' Column ordinal: 17, Expected data type: VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value: VendorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this line.
```

Comment: What **datatype** is your `total_amount` column?

Comment: it is varchar(50) NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @N VARCHAR(MAX) = '10.8';

SELECT total_amount = CASE
                      WHEN @N IS NULL THEN 0 
                      WHEN @N = '' then 0 
                      ELSE
                      CAST(@N AS DECIMAL(10,4) )  
END
```

The problem with your original code is that the datatype of the `CASE` expression is `INT`.

This is because it has two branches returning an integer constant `0` and one branch returning a `varchar` and `int` has [higher datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than `varchar`.

So it first tries to implicitly cast the string `'10.8'` as `int` and fails.

With the rewrite above the `varchar` branch now becomes `decimal(10,4)`. This is higher precedence than `int`, the datatype of the `CASE` expression as a whole now becomes `decimal(10,4)` and there is no problem.

Result:

```
+==============+
| total_amount |
+==============+
|      10,8000 |
+--------------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/OOE29391)**.